# Formatting field in a LINQ expression

Tags: linq, format

I am trying to render a chart from the following query:

Questionnaires created by month and format the month as mm/YYYY

My code:

```
    public ActionResult QuestionnairesByMonth() {

        var query = TrialDB.Questionnaires
            .GroupBy(r => new {
                Month = r.DateCreated.Month,
                Year = r.DateCreated.Year,
            })
            .Select(group => new {
                Date = string.Format("{0}/{1}", group.Key.Year, group.Key.Month),
                Total = group.Count()
            })
            .ToList();

        var chart = new Chart(400, 200)
            .AddTitle("Questionarios creados por mes")
            .DataBindTable(query, "Date")
            .Write();

        return null;
    }
```

but I'm getting the following error :

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I think this is a Linq to EntityFramwork question? Can you add a tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you fetch everything you need in a "simple" Select query which will go to the database, and then perform the formatting locally using `AsEnumerable` to switch to an in-process query:

```
var query = TrialDB.Questionnaires
    .GroupBy(r => new {
        Month = r.DateCreated.Month,
        Year = r.DateCreated.Year,
    })
    .Select(group => new {
        group.Key.Year,
        group.Key.Month,
        Total = group.Count()
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.Total, Date = string.Format("{0}/{1}", x.Year, x.Month))
    .ToList();
```

Or leave it as a `DateTime` when pulling it back from the database, as Stuart suggests:

```
var query = TrialDB.Questionnaires
    .GroupBy(r => new {
        Month = r.DateCreated.Month,
        Year = r.DateCreated.Year,
    })
    .Select(group => new {
        Date = group.Key,
        Total = group.Count()
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => x.Total,
                 Date = string.Format("{0}/{1}", x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month))
    .ToList();
```

For more on `AsEnumerable()`, read my [Edulinq blog post on it](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think the database itself doesn't understand the `string.Format("{0}/{1}", group.Key.Year, group.Key.Month)` - so you'll need to pull back the information as a DateTime, and then format the date in your presentation layer.